# Specify vertical space between outlines (enumerate) levels

Tags: enumerate, itemize, line-spacing

I'm using the `outlines` package, and I'm curious to know how to modify the vertical spacing between entries/items in the outline. I'm happy with using `\onehalfspacing` for the vertical spacing between lines in a single entry/item.  But how can I set the space between different entries/items to something else (for example to doublespacing)?

Here is a working example in which the line spacing is set to onehalf.  How can I modify it so that the entries/items in the outline are more than onehalf spaced apart?  (This working example has some customizations with which the currently-requested solution would need to be compatible.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}        
\usepackage{setspace}

% Outlines configurations
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\roman*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myoutline}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ol@type}{#1}}%
  \ol@z%
  \newcommand{\0}{\ol@toz\ol@z}%
  \newcommand{\1}{\ol@toi\scshape\bfseries\LARGE\ol@i\item}%
  \newcommand{\2}{\ol@toii\normalfont\Large\bfseries\ol@ii\item}%
  \newcommand{\3}{\ol@toiii\normalfont\normalsize\ol@iii\item}%
  \newcommand{\4}{\ol@toiiii\normalfont\normalsize\ol@iiii\item}%
}{%
  \ol@toz\ol@exit%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
\1 Mathematics
    \2 The study of topics such as quantity (numbers), structure, space, and change. There is a range of views among mathematicians and philosophers $\ldots$
    \2 Often, mathematics is conceptually divided into two camps: applied and pure mathematics.  In reality, however, mathematics does not rigidly abide by this dichotomy.
\1 Computer Science
    \2 Computer Science (abbreviated CS or CompSci) is the scientific and practical approach to computation and its applications. It is the systematic study of the $\ldots$
        \3 Famous computer scientists
            \4 Charles Babbage
            \4 Donald Knuth
        \3 History of computer science
\end{outline}


\end{document}
```

Ideally, I'm looking for a solution where I can just modify a single scalar value, such as something like:

```
  \newcommand{\outlinespacingscalar}{1.5}
```

so that I can adjust this scalar to get the look and feel that seems best for a given document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I renewed the definition of the `outline` environment, sticking in a `\vspace` that employs the value of `outlinespacingscalar`, as requested.  I took your request to mean you only wanted the extra space for instances of `\1`, though clearly different values of gap could likewise be set for the other instances.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}        
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{setspace}

% Outlines configurations
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{label=\roman*.}
\setenumerate[4]{label=\alph*.}
\makeatletter
% the outline environment provides commands \1..\4 for
% introducing items at level 1..4, and \0 for normal paragraphs
% within the outline section.
\renewenvironment{outline}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ol@type}{#1}}%
  \ol@z%
  \newcommand{\0}{\ol@toz\ol@z}%
  \newcommand{\1}{\vspace{\dimexpr\outlinespacingscalar\baselineskip-\baselineskip}\ol@toi\ol@i\item}%
  \newcommand{\2}{\ol@toii\ol@ii\item}%
  \newcommand{\3}{\ol@toiii\ol@iii\item}%
  \newcommand{\4}{\ol@toiiii\ol@iiii\item}%
}{%
  \ol@toz\ol@exit%
}
\makeatother
\def\outlinespacingscalar{1.5}

\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
\1 Mathematics
    \2 The study of topics such as quantity (numbers), structure, space, and change. There is a range of views among mathematicians and philosophers $\ldots$
    \2 Often, mathematics is conceptually divided into two camps: applied and pure mathematics.  In reality, however, mathematics does not rigidly abide by this dichotomy.
\1 Computer Science
    \2 Computer Science (abbreviated CS or CompSci) is the scientific and practical approach to computation and its applications. It is the systematic study of the $\ldots$
        \3 Famous computer scientists
            \4 Charles Babbage
            \4 Donald Knuth
        \3 History of computer science
\end{outline}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No need to load `outlines` more than once.

Comment: @Werner Woops, that was my mistake.

Comment: @Werner Fixed..

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using `enumitem` you can add an `itemsep=` and/or `parsep=` to the `\setenumerate`:

[image]

Below I have defined `\ItemSpacing` and `\ParSpacing` both of which are applied to *all* the list levels, but you could define a separate one for each level if desired.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}        
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\ItemSpacing}{15pt}%
\newcommand{\ParSpacing}{10pt}%

% Outlines configurations
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{itemsep={\ItemSpacing},parsep={\ParSpacing},label=\Roman*.}
\setenumerate[2]{itemsep={\ItemSpacing},parsep={\ParSpacing},label=\Alph*.}
\setenumerate[3]{itemsep={\ItemSpacing},parsep={\ParSpacing},label=\roman*.}
\setenumerate[4]{itemsep={\ItemSpacing},parsep={\ParSpacing},label=\alph*.}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myoutline}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\ol@type}{#1}}%
  \ol@z%
  \newcommand{\0}{\ol@toz\ol@z}%
  \newcommand{\1}{\ol@toi\scshape\bfseries\LARGE\ol@i\item}%
  \newcommand{\2}{\ol@toii\normalfont\Large\bfseries\ol@ii\item}%
  \newcommand{\3}{\ol@toiii\normalfont\normalsize\ol@iii\item}%
  \newcommand{\4}{\ol@toiiii\normalfont\normalsize\ol@iiii\item}%
}{%
  \ol@toz\ol@exit%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{outline}[enumerate]
\1 Mathematics
    \2 The study of topics such as quantity (numbers), structure, space, and change. There is a range of views among mathematicians and philosophers $\ldots$
    \2 Often, mathematics is conceptually divided into two camps: applied and pure mathematics.  In reality, however, mathematics does not rigidly abide by this dichotomy.
\1 Computer Science
    \2 Computer Science (abbreviated CS or CompSci) is the scientific and practical approach to computation and its applications. It is the systematic study of the $\ldots$
        \3 Famous computer scientists
            \4 Charles Babbage
            \4 Donald Knuth
        \3 History of computer science
\end{outline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No need to load `outlines` more than once.

Comment: @Werner Woops, that was my mistake.

Comment: Thanks Peter. One more thing... the `AdditionalItemSpacing` space is only applied between multiple items in a given enum group.  It is not applied between, for example, `\3 Famous computer scientists` and `\4 Charles Babbage`.  Do you know to make the spacing also appear after between consecutive items at different levels, such as between a `\3` and a `\4`?

Comment: @synaptik: Have updated solution which now provides two separate settings. Let me know if that is what you desired.

Comment: This works well - even with negative values for the ParSpacing. What I cannot achieve is to make the first skip above the enumeration smaller (and the skip after the enumeration the same) I would wish it to be just a regular space between lines (i.e the whole enumeration should be leaded like regular text). could this be achieved?

Comment: @user855443: Not sure I fully understand your question. I would suggest you post a new question and include a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem. If it helps, you can use the code here as a start.  Also, reference this question as it seems relevant.